# Need to change the color of the font with CSS transitions

Tags: css-transitions

I'm trying to figure out how to change the background color and font color at the same with a hover.

Only the the background is working.

How do make the font color change too with the background change at the same time.

I want to use the CSS transitions.

```
#top_nav #nav_links a {
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out 0s;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-out 0s;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease-out 0s;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-out 0s;
transition: all 1s ease-out 0s;
}

#top_nav #nav_links a:hover {
-webkit-background: #E5FF17;
-moz-background: #E5FF17;
background: #E5FF17;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To change font color you have to add color property of CSS.

Like this :

color: red;

Or

color : #F00